# composer create-project without output

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install laravel via composer in a windows 8 machine.

I'm running the command "composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist" in an empty folder and I'm getting no output to that command even after waiting for several minutes (no output, neither an error)...

I've tried also changing laravel/laravel to some nonexistan package name like "laravel1234" waiting some kind of error or something but nothing changes. I've to cancel with Ctrl+C

Feel free to tell me if I can update my question with some other information, I think probably I'm doing something wrong. Should I put a composer.json file in the folder? I think that isn't necessary with this command.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11):

The command was slightly wrong as @justrohu said, however I think the lack of output is probably due to network issues.

Try this to see where composer is getting stuck:

```
composer -vvv create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there the command you are running should be like

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name --prefer-dist
```

it is mentioned in here http://laravel.com/docs/quick#installation

Comment: Tried that also but I'm getting the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a bad/slow connection problem, I had this issue yesterday at home! I tried it again from work, it worked! However, joe niland's comment to run the create-project in verbose mode (-vvv) is super helpful because you will not think of it as stuck.. and you will see things moving even if slow! Good luck on your Laravel Journey!

P.S. the command that you've used in your question misses out the project name, however i'm not gonna comment on that because others have commented on that, plus in one of your replies, you've said that you had already tried that.